# Does BERT implicitly model for word count?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

Given that BERT is bidirectional, does it implicitly model for word count in some given text? I am asking in the case of classifying data column descriptions as valid or not. I am looking for a model based on word count, and was wondering if that even needs to be done given BERT is bidirectional.

Answer (score 2):

BERT by default considers "word-piece" tokenization and not "word" tokenization. BERT makes available the `max-sequence length` attribute, which is responsible to limit the number of word-piece tokens in a given sentence, it also ensures processing of an equal number of tokens.